# Fundamental group of the common boundary of two disjoint convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, convex-geometry

Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be two disjoint convex sets. In general the fundamental group of $\partial A$ ($\partial B$)(with the subspace topology) is not trivial (for example let $n=2$ and $A$ be the unit disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$). Now consider $\partial A\cap \partial B$ (also with the subspace topology). Being the common boundary of two convex sets that both have non-empty interior, it seems that it cannot encircle any two-dimension hole, so the fundamental group of it should be trivial. But I cannot prove it or give a counter-example, can someone help me?

Comment: I realize it when I pose this question, so I make an edit. @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: It would be hard (or at least I don't know how) to produce two spheres intersecting as circle, as boundaries of two disjoint balls.

Comment: Now we require $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint. @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: Oh, the "disjoint" was the edit! In that case sorry :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disjoint convex sets can be separated by a hyperplane $H$. Thus $\partial A \cap \partial B \subseteq H$. Also note that $a \in \overline A \cap H$ implies $a \in \partial A$ (if it were an interior point, you would find a ball, which extends to the other side of $H$, a contradiction). Since $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$ are convex, the intersection $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}\cap H = \partial A \cap \partial B \cap H = \partial A \cap \partial B$ is convex, in particular contractible.

Answer (score 1):

The closure of a convex set is convex. And the intersection of two convex sets is convex. So the following set is convex:
$$\overline A \cap \overline B = (A \cup \partial A) \cap (B \cup \partial B) = (A \cap \partial B) \cup (\partial A \cap B) \cup (\partial A \cap \partial B)
$$
But in addition we have $A \cap \partial B \subset \partial A \cap \partial B$ because if $x \in A \cap \partial B$ the $x$ is a limit point of $B \subset \mathbb R^n - A$ and hence $x \in \overline{\mathbb R^n - A} \cap \overline A = \partial A$.

Similarly $\partial A \cap B \subset \partial A \cap \partial B$.

Putting this altogether, it follows that $\overline A \cap \overline B = \partial A \cap \partial B$, and since that set is convex, it is also simply connected, and so its fundamental group is trivial.